# Getting error when running select where to='...'

Tags: sql, postgresql, reserved-words

Trying to run a psql query of the form

```
Select * from x where to='...'
```

Is 'to' a reserved word? Doesn't seem to like it.

Comment: yes it is..you should have looked at the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html) before posting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"to" is indeed a [reserved word in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html), as it is in the ANSI standards of SQL-92, SQL:1999 and SQL:2003.

You can escape it by using double-quotes (") if you absolutely have to, although I recommend you just find a non-reserved name for your column:

```
SELECT *
FROM   x
WHERE  "to" = 3
-- Here^--^
```

Answer (score -1):

Select * from x where [to] ='...'

Comment: Square brackets are used for escaping in [tag:sql-server] not [tag:postgresql]